# how can i move a lot of files on centos from one directory to another?

Tags: centos6

I have been trying to move a lot of files on Centos  6, from one directory to another; I am talking about thousands of `.wav` recordings that fill about 230 GB.

I will use a crontab to do it, and I have this command:

`find /var/spool/asterisk/backups/ -name ".wav" -exec mv /usr/src/scripts/ {} \`

The question is I want to use it with `cp` first instead of `mv` to see how it works, but it doesn't make anything, so how could I know if that one above with `mv` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's not to many files

```
mv /var/spool/asterisk/backups/*.wav /usr/src/scripts/
```

If you have a huge amount of files then that will fail with to long command line and your "find" can take forever since it moves the files one at a time (and in your case wrong way, it is SRC DEST not DEST SRC)

You can use something like

```
find /var/spool/asterisk/backups/ -name "*.wav"|xargs -n 100 mv --target-directory=/usr/src/scripts/
```

Then you move 100 files at a time, should speed up things a little.

To see what it will do you can prefix it with "echo" as in "echo mv ...|head" and then copy&paste one line from the output.

To test a little you can use "cp -a" instead of mv

Comment: i could use the one i put , but this one is useful too , so i will keep it

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was failing on: I was missing the * before the wav between the comas.

Comment: You used `find /var/spool/asterisk/backups/ -name "*.wav" -exec mv /usr/src/scripts/ {} \`? if yes post it as an answer